# error: <identifier> expected with package com.native

Tags: android, react-native

I followed [this instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html) to setup android requirements and initiate a project with *react-native*. When I try to run the application using the command `react-native run-android`, it keeps showing this error then exiting the process.

```
/path/to/native/android/app/src/main/java/com/native/MainActivity.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
package com.native;
            ^
```

Comment: try another project name, not **native**. com.native is not a valid java package name

Comment: Yes It works change the name anything except native

Answer (score 1):

The package name should not be a language tag.
Try the other keyword for the package
**Like**

`package com.nativeapp` or `package com.appnative`

Answer (score 1):

As android relies on java to compile code, packages names fall under java reserved words restrictions, `native` is one of them. full list [in Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html).

You also will have to avoid javascript reserved keyword defined in [ECMA documentation](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-keywords-and-reserved-words).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing any other package name as given package name is not a valid package name for android/java.